# React.js token header authorization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt, bearer-token

hi i want to access the autorization header token access and store in a session storage when i do that it returns me null maybe i did some mistake in my code and i dont know where

login form function

```
submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',

                Accept: 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
        }).then((response) => {
            const jwtToken = response.headers.get('Authorization');
            console.log(response);
            if (jwtToken === null) {
                sessionStorage.setItem('Bearer', jwtToken);
            } else {
                return response.json();
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    console.log(this.state);
};
```

Comment: Welcome! please add the output from the `console.log(response)`

Comment: is gives me null

Comment: If you are using Postman, what is the response from localhost:8080/login?

Comment: When i put the credentials in postmanand use method post with api localhost:8080/login it returns me the bearer token https://prnt.sc/10h0zdm

Comment: If you are saying that `console.log(response)` returns `null`, so `const jwtToken = response.headers.get('Authorization');` will throw an error (cannot read property `headers` of `null`), are you getting this error?

Comment: no i dont get i only get value null on sessionstorage

Comment: So, please include to your question the output of `console.log(response);`?